# How to execute a program from GitHub (no .sln-file or .win32-file)?

Tags: visual-studio, github, cmake

I want to execute (e.g. with Visual Studio) the following program from Github: https://github.com/VBot2410/A_Star_3D

I am new to coding, GitHub, etc. and don't know how to do that.
Another thread on Stack Overflow suggested to open the `.sln` file, but I could not find one in this project. Another thread recommended to download CMake and open a `.win32` file, but this is also not in the project files.

Comment: This repository says in the code has *only* been tested on "*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with GCC 5.4.0*". Are you looking to run this code on Windows? If so, it does not appear that this is supported, and may not work as expected...

Comment: Yes, I want to run it on Windows. So how do I at least try to run it? Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly supported, you can try to run this code on Windows. First, you must download the source code and built it.

The repository provides these instructions for Linux, but they are almost identical for Windows. Be sure you have installed [CMake](https://cmake.org/install/) and Visual Studio before running the steps. From a command prompt, run the following commands from the directory where you want the repository to be downloaded and built:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/VBot2410/A_Star_3D
cd A_Star_3D
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

This will configure and build the program, assuming there are no errors, or issues related to the Windows environment. This will generate a Visual Studio solution file (`.sln`) in the `build` folder. You can open this file to view the code, and debug/execute the program(s).

Comment: Unfortunately it says that the command "cmake" was not found. I downloaded and installed cmake-3.17.1-win64-x64.msi on cmake.org/download/

Comment: You may need to add the path to the `cmake.exe` binary to your `Path` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, after doing that it says command "git" was not found. I also added "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" but it shows the same message.

Comment: Yes, you will also need Git to be installed and visible in your path. The path to the `git` executable (`git.exe`) should be `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

Comment: Git is installed and I also added ```C:\Program Files\Git\bin``` as well as ```C:\Program Files\Git\cmd``` but it still shows the same message

Comment: @Dnk8000 Did you close your current command prompt, and re-open a new one? This will load the *new* environment based on the `Path` variable you updated.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right! the first three commands worked but ```cmake --build .``` did not:

```Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/*****/A_Star_3D/app/CMakeLists.txt
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument/Wextra. [C:\Users\*****\A_Star_3D\build\app\A_Star-app.
vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/*****/A_Star_3D/vendor/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument/Wextra. [C:\Users\*****\A_Star_3D\build\vendor\googlete
st\googletest\gtest.vcxproj]```

Comment: I tried compiling but the following error showed up: ```D8021 invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'```

Comment: @Dnk8000 Yes, again, it looks like this repository was catered to run in a Linux environment, and thus, you are seeing errors trying to build it on Windows. Specifically, there are several flags used in the top-level CMake file that are specific to a Linux compiler. You will likely have to modify these to work for Windows.